# What layout manager will do this?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

OY, not enough rep points to post an image...

```
____________________________________________________
|joes pizza                                         |
|          pizza type  toppings         ----------- |
|                                       |         | |
|          cheese       mushrooms       | 15.00   | |
|          veggie       extra cheese    |         | |
|          pepperoni    bacon           |         | |
|                                       ----------  |
|  _______________________________________________  |
|  |  calculate total                             | |
|  ------------------------------------------------ |
|___________________________________________________|
```

I'm supposed to build this for class, where the options in the middle are radio buttons and check boxes, and I have all the components in my panels in my frame.  All I have left to do is actionListener and make it look like this.  We are learning Layout Managers, and have been given five (FlowLayout, BorderLayout, GridLayout, BoxLayout, CardLayout, and GridBagLayout).

I can't seem to make any of them look like this, though.  They either all end up in a line or in some crazy staggered representation, or crowded in from border to border.  Any suggestions?  In case my setup is getting in the way, I have joe's pizza in a label, pizza type in a pane, toppings in a pane, the textArea on the right, and finally a button.  I'm not looking for an answer or the code to make it happen, just want to know what tools I should be using.  If I can't figure out the tools, I'll ask another question or ask in the comments. Thanks for any suggestions.

Tony

Comment: You can nest panels with different layouts. For example, you can use a BorderLayout with a panel in the center which has GridLayout.

Comment: You are going to have to use multiple panels with best fit layouts for each of them.

Comment: Is it possible to put a panel in a panel?  Or may a panel only go in a frame?

Comment: @user3277465 - read the javadoc and/or try it and see.

Comment: BorderLayout, GridLayout and GridBagLayout using component layouts...

Comment: @BheshGurung You don't "have" to use multiple layouts, you could accomplish this using just GridBagLayout, if you're feeling really adventurous, but a compound layout approach will make significantly easier all round ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest `JPanels` with different layouts. Here is one way to go about it. Picture should say it all.

[image]

Comment: Super awesome.  Picture and a thousand words and all that. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @user3277465 note the left side of the center panel is an empty panel and the right side with the border used a `GirdBagLayout` to get the label centered.