# Button Layout in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlist

So I am working in java, and have the buttons set up. The only thing I want to do now is separate the buttons by putting so many on one side of the `JFrame` and so many on the other side of the `JFrame`. Any suggestions? oh and there is a `JList` that goes with one of the buttons.

[Update] Just updated my code, and so far, no improvement, still states that it won't open up the GUI.

```
  package SystemandDesign.RISK;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//Now for the JList options;

import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
//Will be used to created JList options

//Colors to be used for testing purposes.

import java.awt.Color;

//panel to separate buttons.
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class GamePage extends JFrame{

  private JButton surrender;
  private JButton draw;
  private JButton attackRoll;
  private JButton defendRoll;
  private JButton trade;
  private JButton main;
  private JButton quit;
  private JFrame frame;
  private JPanel east;
  private JPanel west;



  private JList terNames;//Used primarily at the beginning of the game to reinforce territories.
  //terNames is also used to reinforce current owned areas.
  private JList terAttack;//Fills up as terrritories that are able to attack
  private static final String[] terProp = {"A-bombing site", "'A'ir-defense", "AA-testing",
    "A hint", "A-field", "'A'ir Force", "A-prep", "A-landing"};
  private static final Color[] terColor = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN,Color.PINK,
    Color.ORANGE,Color.MAGENTA,Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.YELLOW};//The use of colors is being used to test if the List is
  //responsive. Will later be taken out and replaced to highlight territories.



  public GamePage(){

    super("Risk");
    //set up the borders

    frame.add(east,BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    east.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
    west.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));

    //JList
    terNames = new JList(terProp);
    terNames.setVisibleRowCount(3);
    terNames.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    west.add(new JScrollPane(terNames));

    terNames.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
      public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event){
        getContentPane().setBackground(terColor[terNames.getSelectedIndex()]);
      }
    }
                                      );



    //First set the buttons. 
    //These will include the options to surrender:
    //Trade Cards
    //Draw Cards
    //Roll your attack dice
    //Roll your defense dice

    //JButtons
    surrender = new JButton("Surrender");
    draw = new JButton("Draw");
    attackRoll = new JButton("Attack");
    defendRoll = new JButton("Defend");
    trade = new JButton("Trade");
    main = new JButton("Main Menu");
    quit = new JButton("Quit");
    east.add(quit);
    east.add(main);
    west.add(surrender);
    west.add(draw);
    west.add(attackRoll);
    west.add(defendRoll);
    west.add(trade);


    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
    surrender.addActionListener(handler);
    draw.addActionListener(handler);
    attackRoll.addActionListener(handler);
    defendRoll.addActionListener(handler);
    trade.addActionListener(handler);
    main.addActionListener(handler);
    quit.addActionListener(handler);
    //End of JButtons
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
    new GamePage();
  }
  //This is to handle the Buttons.
  private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

      if(event.getSource().equals(surrender)){
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(draw)){
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(attackRoll)){
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(defendRoll)){
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(trade)){
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(quit)){
        dispose();
      }
      else if(event.getSource().equals(main)){
        dispose();
        MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        mainPage.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainPage.setSize(900,600);
        mainPage.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: _"Any suggestions?"_ - Yea, show us some code. If you have none, then get started.

Comment: Here is the code I been working on. Just need to get the buttons to separate, but for some reason I can not get the GUI to show up because there is an error in the code preventing it to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't create another `JFrame`, since your class is already a `JFrame`. OR just use the instance `JFrame` and don't extend `JFrame` for the class. See [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the the program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22003802/2587435)
2. You are trying to add the buttons to the instance `JFrame` and the `JScrollPane` to the class `JFrame` you need to choose one or the other and stick to it.
3. Use `JPanel` or `JComponent` as a container and not `Container`
4. You can nest containers (`JPanels`) with different layout managers to get your desired look. See [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for help if your confused. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21948852/2587435) for how you can use nested `JPanels` with different layout managers.
5. *"oh and there is a `JList` that goes with one of the buttons."* - doesn't really make sense.
6. I see you trying to dispose of your main frame and opening a new one. Don't do that. Instead use a `CardLayout`. The layout will *"layer"* panels and allow you to navigate through them. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Also see a simple example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21460065/2587435)

Answer (score 2):

You can create two JPanels into which you put your different buttons as you wish, then using a suitable layout on the JFrame (BorderLayout, GridBagLayout, there are a few possibilities), add the panels.

Comment: what if I have the JFrame preset to FlowLayout, I can still input the JPanels to set it to both sides?

Comment: Can't you change the layout?

Comment: Sure, so import java.awt.BorderLayout along with import java.awt.JPanel correct?